# How to account for ampersands in xml with xmlformatter

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm still learning Python, so please bear with me if my approach below seems noobish.  I am writing a program that will read in an xml file and add in missing nodes.  I am using Python's ElementTree to browse through the xml and make the changes.

Unfortunately, ElementTree doesn't format the added in xml.  It just leaves it all in a single line.  So to fix this, I have imported xmlformatter.  xmlformatter works great, but it's changing my (ampersand quot semi-colon) to actual quotes inside the xml because the xml file in question has '&'s being used to represent quotes.

Here is an example of the xml code:

```
    <override action="replaceElement" path="pdf-        
    list/pdf[@name="HfsSdbWks" ]">
    <element name="pdf">
    <attribute name="size" value="186"></attribute>
    <attribute name="name" value="HfsSdbWks"></attribute>
    <attribute name="path" 
    value="/clientFolder/downloads/HFS_SDB_Wks.pdf"> 
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="devPath" 
    value="/clientFolder/downloads/HFS_SDB_Wks.pdf"></attribute>
    </element>
    </override>
```

So my problem is really: what is the best way to account for those &'s?

My personal approach to fixing this has been to first read the entire file into a string.  Then replace inside that string all occurrences of `&quot;` with `1234abcd` or basically any kind of unique string of chars that keeps the xml intact, that I can then revert back after formatting.

```
    def createPdfOvr(self, ovrCopy):  #these are methods inside a class

    if self.xml_string != '':
        with open(self.OVR_COPY, 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.xml_string)


    def formatXML(self, xml_string):
    formatted_xml =  
    xml.Formatter().format_string(self.xml_string).decode("utf-8")
    self.xml_string = formatted_xml.replace('abc1234', '&quot;')
```

Currently I have the expected results.  Which is an updated xml file that has all the new nodes/attributes, and is formatted to be readable.  Here is the code:

```
    overrides parent="runtime/view/PDF.xml" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FndtOverridesSchema.xsd">
    <override action="replaceElement" path="pdf- 
   list/pdf[@name=&quot;HfsSdbWks&quot; ]">
   <element name="pdf">
   <attribute name="size" value="186"></attribute>
   <attribute name="name" value="HfsSdbWks"></attribute>
   <attribute name="path" 
   value="/01040_ybr_ybrfndt/downloads/HFS_SDB_Wks.pdf"></attribute>
   <attribute name="devPath" 
   value="/01040_ybr_ybrfndt/downloads/HFS_SDB_Wks.pdf"></attribute>
   </element>
   </override>
   <----This is the new node that was added---->
   <override action="replaceElement" path="pdf- 
   list/pdf[@name=&quot;Hippa&quot; ]">
   <element name="pdf">
   <attribute name="size" value="129"></attribute>
   <attribute name="name" value="Hippa"></attribute>
   <attribute name="path" value="/01040_ybr_ybrfndt/downloads/Hippa.pdf"> 
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="devPath" 
   value="/01040_ybr_ybrfndt/downloads/Hippa.pdf"></attribute>
   </element>
   </override>
```

Comment: "Currently I have the expected results." So what is the problem?

Comment: Well since I'm new to python, I just wanted to be sure my method wasn't wasting time reinventing the wheel.  I think my method works and will get the job done,  but I want to see what other's would suggest.

Comment: Something like your workaround is needed. From an XML point of view, the entity reference `&quot;` and a literal quotation mark are equivalent. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3502437/407651.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, parsing XML and then re-serializing it will lose information that XML deems to be not significant - for example, extra spaces between attributes in a start tag, the order of attributes, redundant namespace declarations, or the distinction between `&quot;` and `"`.

If it's really important to you to retain this information, then you should first be asking why? If an XML parser doesn't care about a distinction, then why do you? One possible answer is that your workflow involves hand editing of the XML after transformation. I've certainly been in that position myself, and in such circumstances I have resorted to the same kind of workarounds that you are using.

Comment: Ty that's quite helpful.